# Finding outliers in uniformly distributed data

Tags: statistics, outliers

My dataset has 2 columns Category and Price. Price column has uniformly distributed data. I want to find the outliers from Price column for each category

```
Category     Price<br>
A &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;5<br>
A &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;12<br>
A &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;14<br>
A &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;15<br>
A &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;22<br>
B &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;100<br>
B &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;2000<br>
B &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;3000<br>
B &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;4000<br>
B &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;9500<br>
```

I have tried IQR but its not providing accurate results

I expect that for category A it should give 5 and 22 as outliers and for category B the outlier should be 100 and 9500

Comment: what is the result of IQR?

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Detecting outliers in a linear sample is a well-documented problem, with posted solutions in many languages.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to seperate your dataframe into category A and B.

```
dfA = df.loc[df['Category'] == 'A']
dfB = df.loc[df['Category'] == 'B']
dfAquantile = dfA['Price'].quantile(0.25)
...
```